# Meaning of かっぱ寿司では

Tags: meaning, expressions

I found an article [here](https://www.excite.co.jp/news/article/Cobs_2000521/), and the first sentence contains fragment ~かっぱ寿司では~. Can not translate it - what does it mean? The complete sentence: 回転寿司チェーンかっぱ寿司では、12月13日から「本格ラーメンシリーズ」の第八弾として金澤濃厚中華そば神仙監修の「神系金澤味噌ラーメン」を全国の店舗で発売する。

Comment: You're aware that かっぱ寿司 is just the name of the sushi chain, right? Are you trying to understand the meaning of the name, how it fits into the grammar of the sentence, or something else?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't knew that.. But just for interest - where かっぱ～ is coming from?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_(folklore) たぶんこれだと思います